# what is the command that prints the current PATH (window`s API, using c++)

Tags: c++, winapi, windows-shell

I am programming a basic win shell in c++ and one of the request is to support the function that prints the current ("chosen") path(basically does what "echo %cd%" does)...
can some one please post the command name and/or usage. I have been searching google for about a hour

Comment: [`GetCurrentDirectory()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/windows/desktop/aa364934(v=vs.85).aspx)?

Comment: -1: An hour isn't a very long time. You're expected to get used to performing your own research. If that means you have to read through the WinAPI docs for a day or two, then so be it ... and you'll be better off for it because afterwards you'll know where to look for things in future. Spoon-feeding you function names doesn't teach you anything at all. Also, you may wish to work on improving your searching skills, because the answer is literally the first result for `windows api current directory` on Google.

Comment: Maybe your user referred to `PATH`, which has nothing to do with current directory?

Answer (score 2):

The function you're looking for is [`GetCurrentDirectory`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa364934%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

You were probably having difficulty finding it because you didn't know what words to search for. I found it by searching for "windows api get working directory."

Answer (score 2):

**The WinAPI function is:**
[GetCurrentDirectory](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/windows/desktop/aa364934(v=vs.85).aspx)  
The link shows C++ usage of that WinAPI function.

**Here is an example that uses the function in a full console program:**
 [Changing The Current Directory](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/windows/desktop/aa363806(v=vs.85).aspx)

**This function is platform specific:**
[windows.h](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows.h) > winbase.h > [kernel32.dll](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_Windows_library_files#KERNEL32.DLL)

Comment: It's a WinAPI function, not a C++ function.

Comment: @BarryTheHatchet the person is explicitly asking for a winapi function so I don't see the problem...?

Comment: He didn't say it was a problem, simply that I called in a C++ function, possibly implying that it's part of the ISO C++ standard or something, when it's really a Microsoft library.

Comment: Yes, exactly that.

Comment: Ah I see; all right. Disregard then ^^

Comment: Like any other function in the Windows API, this, too, is exported as C. There is no C++ in the Windows API.